# Java error Package does not exist

Tags: java, testing, import, directory, package

My main folder is ABC inside it is 2 folders named classes and src, inside src is 2 folders named objectFile and testFile, inside objectFile is ABC.java while inside testFile is TestABC.java.(inside classes is the same but .class instead) now ABC contains

```
package objectFile;
public class ABC
private int something;
```

while TestABC.java contains

```
package testFile;
import objectFile.ABC;

public class TestABC
```

error says TestABC.java:2: error: package objectFile does not exist

import objectFile.ABC;

Comment: That should work. How are you compiling your classes? Are you using an IDE (like NetBeans or eclipse)? Try cleaning you project (deleting the _.class_ files), and building (compiling) it again.

Comment: nope im using cmd(required), tried to clean them but still didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you specifying the [sourcepath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#sourcepath)? This tells the compiler where to find the classes that it needs to import.

```
javac -sourcepath src -d classes src\testFile\TestABC.java
```

Note that this compiles not just *TestABC.java*, but *ABC.java* as well (because of your `import` statement).

You can then put the classes into an archive using the `jar` command:

```
jar cfe myJavaArchive.jar testFile/TestABC -C classes .
```

This will **c**reate a new jar with the **f**ilename *myJavaArchive.jar* and **e**ntrypoint *testFile/TestABC* made from all the files in the *classes* directory.

Because it is the entry point, TestABC must have a `main` method, e.g.

```
package testFile;

import objectFile.ABC;

public class TestABC {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ABC abc1 = new ABC(1);
        ABC abc2 = new ABC(2);

        System.out.println("abc1.i is " + abc1.getI());
        System.out.println("abc2.i is " + abc2.getI());
    }
}
```

and

```
package objectFile;

public class ABC {

    private int i;

    public ABC(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Then you can execute the code using the `java -jar` command:

```
java -jar myJavaArchive.jar
```

Comment: I did as you said and it worked i compiled it into a class but theres a problem when i run the jar file, it says could not find or load main class

Comment: I've added instructions on how to specify the entry point when creating a jar.